# Backendless - Trying to retrieve specific data from Users table

Tags: java, android, backendless

I'm making an app for my final project in school..

I've made an Login page and inside the login page I need to retrieve a data from a specific column named `Permissions` and then check the permission to declare to which next Activity the app will take the user..

In simple words I need something like this:

```
public void login(View view){ //button
   if(Permission == admin){ // get the permission from the user that is logging in.. lets say from username = "Bob123"
      //do something.. 
      }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the [Data retrieval documentation](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_basic_search.htm)?

Comment: not able to get the permission of a user from the Users table

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to:

create an instance of BackendlessUser in your application class:

```
    public static BackendlessUser user;
```

If you have added the permission column to the Users table and you have made the email an identity column in the schema you can use the following code to retrieve a `BackendlessUser` object and direct the user to the correct `Activity` based on his `permission` in the `Users` table:

```
public void login(String emailToLogin){
                DataQueryBuilder dataQueryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder.create();
                dataQueryBuilder.setWhereClause("email = " + "'" + emailToLogin + "'");
                Backendless.Data.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(dataQueryBuilder,
                        new AsyncCallback<List<BackendlessUser>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(List<BackendlessUser> response) {
                        if (response.get(0).getProperty("permission").equals("permissionOne")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, permissionOneActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }//end if

                        else if (response.get(0).getProperty("permission").equals("permissionTwo")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, permissionTwoActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }//end else if

                    }//end handleResponse

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                        //add error handling here...
                    }//end handleFault
                });}
```

In the code mentioned below, the `response.get(0)` will always return the correct user since we are getting the `BackendlessUser` object based on his email that we set to be a Unique Identifier.

"permissionOne" and "permissionTwo" is whatever you have called your permissions, eg. "permissionOne" takes you to the admin `Activity` and "permissionTwo" takes you to the clients `Activity`.

```
response.get(0).getProperty("permission").equals("permissionOne")
```

This code `myUserObject.getProperty("myColumnName");` retrieves any property you want from the Users table in Backendless

Hope this helps somebody.